# regex for numerics and decimals in java

Tags: java, regex, validation

Need a regex that allows the following valid values.(only decimals and numbers are allowed)

**valid :**

```
.1  
1.10  
1231313  
0.32131  
31313113.123123123
```

**Invalid :**

```
dadadd.31232  
12313jn123  
dshiodah
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be strict on your allowed matches:

```
^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$
```

**Explanation**:

```
^         # the beginning of the string
 [0-9]*   #  any character of: '0' to '9' (0 or more times)
 \.?      #  '.' (optional)
 [0-9]+   #  any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
$         # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yM6eD0/4)

Answer (score 3):

You can try the regular expression:

```
^(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>* Image generated using [*Debuggex: Online visual regex tester*](https://www.debuggex.com).</sub>

The explanation of this regular expression:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

<sub>* Explanation from [*Explain Regular Expressions*](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String input = "0.32131";

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.?\\d+");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(input);

if (mat.matches())
    System.out.println("Valid!");
else
    System.out.println("Invalid");
```

Comment: perfect and thanks .just need another regex only for decimals and not numerics 
valid  :: .1,0.113131,4242424.23423424

Comment: also i want to know what is the need of pattern.compile ,we can just do the straight away like string.matches(regex) which will return true or false

Comment: your expression will say that `0.321.31` is valid

Comment: oops @alfasin thanks to point out ,i haven't check this value

Comment: @user2841408 My expression is fixed now. And about your question: using `Pattern.compile()` is a good idea when a regular expression needs to be reused. In this way, we only have to create it _once_, but matching results as many times as needed. This is more efficient than using `String.matches()`, which re-compiles the same expression every time it's called.